# where can we Obtain the Cloudera/HORTONWORKS EFM Server Binaries

Tags: cloudera-cdh

we want integrate CDF in our system. From the  [install document](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/CEM/CEM-1.0.0/installation/content/install-efm-server.html), we cat not find where to download the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in Cloudera Edge Management package.